# multiple databases with same name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have to host multiple(24) databases with the same name on one server.
How can I realize this?
Is the best way to use different Instances?
Ì use sql server 2019

Comment: Please specify RDBMS you use. In case of SQL Server I guess you should use different instances

Comment: Setting up multiple instances for this is going to be quite painful. How certain is the requirement that they have the same name? Because if it's flexible enough to work against multiple instances on a single machine, it's almost certainly flexible enough to work with different names.

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem. Why on earth do you think you need multiple databases with the same name?